# Open a file with a batch script and manipulate it

Tags: file, batch-file, return

I am working on a big project. When a user double clicks on a file with a certain file extension it opens it with a batch and checks the file for certain keywords.

---

I am not asking for people to type up the code for me. I just want to know how to set a default program for a file to a batch script and then have that batch script do something with the contents of the file. How do I do this?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You can't set a specific batch script as a default program because it's not a program. The best you can do is to drag the file onto the batch script and process the file, which should be referenced in the script as `%1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your windows version you should be able to:

1. Right click the file
2. Choose open with
3. Choose choose another app
4. Choose More Apps
5. Scroll to the bottom and Look for another app on this pc.
6. Select your file.

To do it via the command line (you'll need an elevated one).

```
ASSOC .ttt=TTTHandler
FTYPE TTTHandler=c:\temp\openttt2.bat "%1"
```

This will associate the batch file `c:\temp\openttt2.bat` with the `.ttt` extension.

Contents of my `openttt2.bat` test file:

```
echo Hello from ttt file opener. File passed = %1
pause
```